# attempting to connect to sybase but resolving to mssql adapter

Tags: activerecord, jruby, sap-iq

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'jdbc/jtds'
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
config = {
  :username => 'me',
  :password => 'mypass',
  :adapter => 'jdbc',
  :driver => 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver',
  :url => 'jdbc:jtds:sybase://myserver:1234/mydb'
}
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( config )
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class
#  => ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MssqlJdbcConnection
```

I realise that MSSQL and Sybase have a shared history, but is it correct that I get this adapter when connecting to Sybase?

My problem is that types are not being mapped to ruby type correctly.  e.g. floats and, decimals are being translated to String.

Gems:

- activerecord-jdbc-adapter 1.1.3
- jdbc-jtds 1.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord will resolved the JDBC adapter by adding the

```
:dialect => 'sybase'
```

...config option